# Pinterest Pin It button overlaps neighbouring content

Tags: html, social-networking, pinterest

I have a Pinterest button that shows the count beside the button. The problem is that the count is displayed with `position:absolute;` so it overlaps the button right next to it like here:

[image: Pinterest Button Overlap]

Is there an elegant solution to make it not overlap without increasing space between buttons? Here's the code I used to display the button (from the Pinterest Widget Builder):

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbooks.popublic.com%2Fnotmyuniverse%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Fbooks.popublic.com%2Fnotmyuniverse%2Fimage%2Fcover.jpg&description=%22Not%20My%20Universe%22%20by%20Z.V.%20Mara" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside" data-pin-zero="true" data-pin-color="red"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_red_20.png" /></a>
```

Comment: I asked the Pinterest support about this and they responded: "We don't have an official way to solve this at this point. The only workaround I can think of is to add extra padding around the button itself to compensate for the counter. I've let others on the engineering team know about this issue so that we can get this permanently resolved."

Answer (score 0):

May this will solve your problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pinit"><a data-pin-config="beside" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=;media=" data-pin-do="buttonPin"></a>  </div>
```

**css**

```
.pinit a{ 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:auto!important;
    min-width:40px!important;
}
.pinit span{
    position:relative!important;
    display:block;
    margin-left:42px!important;
    left:0!important
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution where I wouldn't have to choose an absolute size in case Pinterest changes it's API without notice.

Comment: yes i am agree but this is just quick fix till we don't have any true solution. I used this working fine so just want to share.

Comment: Ya my current method is pretty much identical. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this, was to put the Pinterest button at the end. IE the far right.